# Cannot find certificate in Trusted Publishers store

Tags: c#, x509certificate, x509, x509certificate2

I want to find a certificate in StoreLocation.LocalMachine by thumbprint, however, I found that if I don't specify the `StoreName`, I don't get anything:

```
certStore = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
     X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
// always find nothing, no matter runs as Administrator or not.
```

but if I specify the `StoreName` when initializing X509Store, I can find the certificate.

```
certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPublisher, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
   X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
```

MSDN doesn't say the difference between `X509Store` constructors, if `StoreName` is not specified, does it mean it searches in all store names? It doesn't look like it's the case to me.

Answer (score 2):

I looked into .NET source code, `X509Store` uses `StoreName.My` when caller doesn't specify the `StoreName`. MSDN doesn't say a word about this behavior.

Comment: what's the default value?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/security/system/security/cryptography/x509/x509store.cs,5a934f012a957b23,references), if you don't specify the store location, like you code below does :

```
certStore = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
```

Then the constructor will use the `Store.My`

```
public X509Store (StoreLocation storeLocation) : this ("MY", storeLocation) {}
```